# Request for clarification of Eigensystem::eivn message

Tags: matrix, bugs, linear-algebra

**Bug introduced in 9.0 or earlier and fixed in version 11.0.1**

---

What causes the problem of "two eigenvectors associated to one single multiplicity eigenvalue" that I am experiencing?

After several transformations to simplify an unwieldy matrix, I end up with the following matrix:

```
tst = 
  {{-0.4, 201.335 b, 0, 0, 0, 0.2, 0, 67.1116 c, 0, 0}, 
   {0, -2.5, 0, 0, 0, 0.000125, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
   {-84.0569 a, 0., -0.0625 + 0.0208333 n, 0., 0.194982, 0., -0.625, -0.0654762, 
      120.081 d, -120.081 e}, 
   {0, -1.52*10^-7, 0, -16., 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
   {0, 0. + 140.934 b, 0, 0., -0.4, 0.14, 0, 46.9781 c, 0, 0}, 
   {-672.455 a, 0., 1.5 + 0.166667 n, 0., 1.55986, -2., -5., -0.52381, 
      960.65 d, -960.65 e}, 
   {336.227 a, 0. + 503.337 b, -0.0833333 n, 0., -0.77993, 0.5, 0, 0.261905 + 167.779 c, 
      -480.325 d, 480.325 e}, 
   {-336.227 a, 0, 0.0833333 n, 0, 0, 0, 0, -0.333333, 480.325 d, -480.325 e}, 
   {0, 0., 0, 0., 0, 0., 0, 0, 0., 0}, 
   {0, 8.3125*10^-12/r^2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,0, 0}}
```

The symbols `a` to `r` stand for lengthy formulae that I plan to resubstitute later on.

I want to compute the eigen system symbolically. However, after

```
Eigensystem[tst];
```

I get the following message:

> Eigensystem::eivn: Incorrect number 2 of eigenvectors for eigenvalue Root[<<14>>+(<<1>>) #1^6+(104.294 r^4+134.491 a r^4+22564.8 a c r^4-0.497321 n r^4) #1^7+(21.6958 r^2-0.0208333 n r^2) #1^8+1. #1^9&,1] with multiplicity 1.

The eigenvalues come out fine. However, the eigenvectors are different from what I expected and I get a rank 6 matrix where I should get a rank 9 one.

The numerical equivalent consistently shows, over the time domain, that this 10 x 10 matrix has rank 9 with two distinct complex eigenvalue pairs, so I cannot figure out where the "two eigenvectors associated to one single multiplicity eigenvalue" message comes from.

When I substitute the time values for the functions currently represented by variables `a` to `r` (I kept the system time invariant), the following can be shown:

```
tst /. 
 {b -> 14.9006, c -> 0.000302268, a -> 0.000505923, n -> 9.85915, 
  e -> 1.01185*10^9, d -> 0.00252961, r -> 0.05}

Eigenvalues[%]
```

> ```
> {-16., -3.20848, -0.57097 + 1.46864 I, -0.57097 - 1.46864 I, -0.4, -0.397966,
> ```

```
 -0.159931 + 0.209588 I, -0.159931 - 0.209588 I, -0.0221849, 0.}
```

What causes this problem of "two eigenvectors associated to one single multiplicity eigenvalue"? How can I avoid this and the different and lower rank eigenvector set is returned?

Comment: You have asked and answered enough questions on this site that you should be aware of the norms for formatting posts that are expected here. Please do a better job of formatting your posts in the future.

Comment: I have to admit I find the formatting here difficult. I realise this is not an excuse so my apologies. I will study your changes to learn from it. Thank you for your effort and support in adjusting this.

Comment: Might be a bug. The tandem of symbolic root objects and approximate numbers could give the internal code some fits. I will remark that if you rationalize the matrix this problem goes away, and the expense of the computation is probably not significantly different.

Comment: Thanks for your help Daniel, performance is not that bad actually (compared to before optimisation which took days). However the reason to go symbolic is that this is a pretty poorly conditioned system. Will rationalisation be recommendable from an accuracy perspective compared to switching to numerical solving?

Comment: Sorry, rationalisation gives same error message and same incorrect eigenvector set (at least on version 9.0.1.0. on i7 Macbook Pro). So I guess the numerical approach is left :)

Comment: Okay. I had tested in version 10. We're regarding this as a bug though I cannot give any prognosis.

Comment: Well, there's a good reason for an upgrade to version 10 then :)

Comment: @Sander Simple `Rationalize[tst]` doesn't help because it leaves some floating point numbers. Try `Rationalize[tst, 10^-10]` instead.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau It seems to work fine in V11.0.0 (Mac OSX) without rationalization -- Can you or someone else confirm that it fails in V11.0.1?

Comment: I just bought the latest version. Will check! Thanks for monitoring this...

Comment: It works okay for V11.01, I changed the bug status message accordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been resolved for version 11.

For versions predating this, use `Rationalize[tst, 10^-10]`