# General::eivn "Incorrect number 3 of eigenvectors for eigenvalue" when calculating Eigenvectors[FourierMatrix[8]]

Tags: matrix, bugs, warning-messages

I just evaluated `Eigenvectors[FourierMatrix[8]]` in Mathematica (version 12.0.0.0) and got a series of errors like:

> Eigensystem::eivn: Incorrect number 3 of eigenvectors for eigenvalue Root[{1+#1^4&,1+#2^2&,4096 #2+2048 #2 #3+512 #3^2+512 #2 #3^2+256 #3^3-17 #1 #3^3+6 #1^3 #3^3-6 #1 #2 #3^3-17 #1^3 #2 #3^3+64 #3^4+64 #2 #3^4+32 #2 #3^5+8 #3^6+8 #2 #3^6+4 #3^7+#3^8&},{4,2,5}] with multiplicity 2.

I'm mainly wondering what the error [`"General::eivn"`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/message/General/eivn.html) means.  The `Eigenvalues` function seems to work just fine, and I'm pretty sure FourierMatrix does have eigenvectors from the matrix being unitary.

Comment: [Related](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/87465/72682). In the [documentation for that message](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/message/General/eivn.html) it says: _"This message indicates an internal failure that should only occur under unusual conditions, such as failure to recognize a combination of symbols that simplifies to zero."_ and also _"If you see this message in an example where it is not expected, please contact Technical Support."_

Comment: You can of course get all the numerical eigenvectors if you don't need them exact and symbolic `Eigenvectors[N@FourierMatrix[8]]`

Comment: In Wolfram Cloud (Mathematica 13.2.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) ) on gets the same message. As commented by @ flinty, *"If you see this message in an example where it is not expected, please contact Technical Support."*

Comment: Reported as a bug

Comment: Just for fun, a comment about time machine. In 1997 (25 years ago) I reported to WRI about a bug in Mathematica 3.0, symbolic Eigenvectors of a square root of unit matrix (taken from Help) gave 3 eigenvectors for an eigenvalue with multiplicity 2. They have fixed it in Mathematica 4.0. So, the bug is back again.

Comment: @innaiz Different bug.

Comment: @Daniel Lichtblau  New is better.

Comment: @innaiz In this instance I fully agree. (Bug in question is fixed for future release, by the way.)